# UIBarbutton 'Save' not appearing again after UIActivity Indicator stops on navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

There is a `Save` (System Item) on my navigation bar as `BarButtonItem` I am showing `UIActivityIndicatorView` on the navigation bar when user clicks this `Save` Button and I want to appear this Barbutton(Save) again on certain condition. First I think the problem is I am adding a indicator on customView so I don't need to hide the barbutton.It automatically hides itself after I start the indicator. But don't know now how to show Save Button again. or how can I remove the indicator from customView

This is how I am doing

```
 @IBOutlet weak var saveButtonOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!
 var activityIndicatorView:UIActivityIndicatorView!
func showActivityIndicator() {

         activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
        activityIndicatorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 14, 14)
        activityIndicatorView.color = UIColor().blueColorIOS()
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView:  activityIndicatorView)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
      }


   @IBAction func saveButtonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        showActivityIndicator()

      ServerRequest.postToServer(url, params: params){
            result, error in
            if let result = result {
                let code =  result["code"] as? Int
                print(result)
                if (code==200){

                    dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { ()->() in

                        self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true
                        self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true
                        //here want to show again "saveButtonOutlet" 

                                       })


                }

            }
        }



    }


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one way to do this is to create the Save button again, and setting the `rightBarButtonItem` again:

```
...
self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true
self.activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Save, target: self, action: "saveButtonClicked:")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

And I'd also replace `self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = true` with `self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()` to properly use the `hidesWhenStopped` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is reset the `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` to the saveButtonOutlet.
Worked right now for me.